# Changing portnumber of localhost in Cordova project

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, cordova, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-cordova

Anyone who knows how to change the default port-number on which a cordova-project runs on localhost? I'm using Visual Studio 2015. In a web-application, you can easily change the portnumber of localhost in the project properties but in a cordova-project, this option doesn't exist. Didn't find a thing about it on the internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Visual Studio 2015 sets your Cordova project to debug using Ripple emulator. I'm assuming you're seeing port 4400 as your default port.

In VS2015, go Tools -> Options. Then Search Options for Ripple Emulator - it's under tools for Apache Cordova. Then change the port number away from 4400 to whatever you want it to be.

Since this is CTP stuff, it might require you saving and restarting Visual Studio.

EDIT: I've provided a screenshot of what I see. I have VS 2015 CTP 6 (latest)

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: That's interesting. I just added a screenshot of what I see. I have VS 2015 CTP 6. I believe that comes with CTP 3.1 of Tools for Apache Cordova.  Maybe this is a CTP 6 enhancement.

Comment: Ok, thank you, it seems like I'm running an older version because I downloaded it in the beginning of February, and CTP6's launch date was near the end of February. Going to download it again in a few hours. I'll be back ;)

Comment: Updating the version worked for me. I was running CTP5. I updated to CTP6 and have the right options to choose from. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

In Order to change the port you need to change the port number in run file from the following location Project_Name>platforms>browser>cordova>lib>run.js

```
 args.port = args.port || 8000; // need to change this
```

That's it, now the execute the command again to run on new port.